# Tomcat starting but not serving default page on 8081

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, jboss, siteminder

Tomcat starting but not serving default page on 8081.

```
Apache tomcat 
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
Server built:   Aug 25 2016 13:23:17 UTC
Server number:  7.0.69.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_111-b15
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

JBoss and tomcat using the same default port 8080, decided to chage the tomcat port 8081 it is not serving the page when we access it: `<server's IP>:8081`, but when we do `<server's IP>:8080` it is serving jboss page.

Comment: IMHO - changing the JBoss Port might be better, more people are used to going to 80/8080 than to 8081, e.g. if tomcat is in front of your JBoss server.  Also depending on the Jboss version - its very simple to change the port

Comment: We have applications using Jboss on default 8080 and don't want to break and trying to use tomcat on 8081 which is not yet used by any application

Comment: Understood and great point does [this](https://clients.javapipe.com/knowledgebase/62/How-to-Redirect-Your-Tomcat-or-JBoss-Over-Port-80.html) possibly help - I'm thinking you may have just overlooked something in the config.

Comment: I was going through many forms and they have mentioned this route to change the port to 8081.

Comment: Before changing the tomcat port it was on the default 8080 and when I try to access it I was getting a 404 error

Comment: when the 404 error occurred, did it show anything interesting in logs that might help you figure it out?

Comment: catalina.out log was empty

Comment: what type of connector are you using between Tomcat and JBoss and what articles did you follow - I can try and get it setup locally